# Is there a way to composite Interceptors

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am new to ByteBuddy and have simple question. Is there any way how to composite interceptors together f.e via annotation. Something like:

```
@Logging
@Transactional
public void foo() {}
```

Would add logging interceptor and also make sure it's transactional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Rafael Winterhalter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237575/rafael-winterhalter) and discussion I am posting his suggested answer:

> You would need to write your own generic dispatcher. I would suggest you to create some form of generic dispatcher which then delegate programmatically. 
>   
>   For example: 
>   `isAnnotatedWith(anyOf(dispatcher.getAnnotationTypes())` where the dispatcher then routes to the components in question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you use a `ByteBuddy` instanace, it is up to the used `ElementMatcher` used:

```
annotatedWith(Logging.class).or(annotatedWith(Transactional.class))
```

When you are using an `AgentBuilder`, you would define one instrumentation for each type where you can combine different type matchers using

```
.type(declaresMethod(annotatedWith(Logging.class)))       
   .transform(new LoggingTranformer())
   .asDecorator()
.type(declaresMethod(annotatedWith(Transactional.class)))
   .transform(new TransactionalTranformer())
   .asDecorator()
```

Using the `asDecorator()` command, the two transformers are chained.

Comment: Thanks Rafael for your answer! Is this .asDecorator() approach possible using only Bytebuddy? I would like to end up having multiple Interceptors but separate each solution to one class since number of combination can be quite big.

Comment: What do you mean with "only possible using Byte Buddy"?

Comment: Sorry, I am clearly missing something. I understood that ByteBuddy instance and AgentBuilder are two distinct approaches.

Do I have to use AgentBuilder to have this chaining approach? 
I was wondering whether I can achieve this chain using .intercept(). 
Like: 
new ByteBuddy(..)
                .with(...).implement(type)        method(annotatedWith(Logging.class).or(annotatedWith(Transactional.class))).intercept(WHAT_PUT_HERE??)

Where if Logging and Transactional presented it will combine both interceptors. If there is going to be only Logging, only one interceptor applied

Comment: Ah, I now see what you mean. I thought you were using the `Advice` class where you can simply register multiple such visitors for a type which automatically chain up. In this case, you would need to write your own generic dispatcher. I would suggest you to create some form of generic dispatcher which then delegate programmatically. For example: `isAnnotatedWith(anyOf(dispatcher.getAnnotationTypes())` where the dispatcher then routes to the components in question.